# How do you rename multiple files by removing 4 characters in the middle that are different in each file name but in the same location?

Tags: bash, rename

I would like to rename my files using Bash by removing 4 characters in the middle.

Original file names:

```
dwe_hiul123456.pdf
dwe_lkyd345876.pdf
dwe_ythn157843.pdf
```

I want to remove the 4 letters in the middle so the new file names would be:

```
dwe_123456.pdf
dwe_345876.pdf
dwe_157843.pdf
```

The 4 letters will always follow the `_` and there will always be one `_` in the file name. All of the file names are the same length the the four characters I want to remove are in the same place.

I'm really new to this and don't know what version of anything I am using other than I am using Windows 10. I was trying to do this through the Git Bash command Window.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are the 4 characters alway the ones following the `_` in the filename? Is there exactly one `_` in the filenames? Please update the question when answering.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using and, if Linux, which one. The tools you have available depend on this information.

Comment: @roaima - That doesn't work for me because the code they wrote is replacing the same text in each file.  My text is different in every file.  All of the file names are the same length the the four characters I want to remove are in the same place.

Comment: "_I am using Windows 10_" strongly implies that you're not asking about [unix.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have perl-rename (available as `rename` on Debian-based systems, `perl-rename` on others), you can do:

```
$ rename -n 's/_..../_/' *pdf
dwe_hiul123456.pdf -> dwe_123456.pdf
dwe_lkyd345876.pdf -> dwe_345876.pdf
dwe_ythn157843.pdf -> dwe_157843.pdf
```

The `-n` causes `rename` to only print what it would do without making any changes. Once you ahve confirmed it works as you want, remove the `-n` and run the command again to actually rename the files:

```
rename 's/_..../_/' *pdf
```

---

If you can't use `rename` for some reason, you can also do it with a simple shell loop:

```
for file in *pdf; do
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file/_????/_}"
done
```

Once again, if you are confident this does what you want, remove the `echo` to actually rename the commands:

```
for file in *pdf; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file/_????/_}"
done
```

Comment: Without the dot `*pdf` would mv files like `dwe_ythn157843pdf`, or there's some reason you use it that way?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity just habit. Extensions aren't really a thing in the *nix world, with very few exceptions, and `*pdf` would match both `foo.pdf` and `foopdf`, so it will work fine for the OP.

Comment: Thank  you!  The second version (without the rename) worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, @hosta. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bsh
$ for i in *.pdf; do
    echo mv -- "$i" "${i/_[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]/_}"
    #  actual `mv` command
    # mv -- "$i" "${i/_[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]/_}"
  done
mv -- dwe_hiul123456.pdf dwe_123456.pdf
mv -- dwe_lkyd345876.pdf dwe_345876.pdf
mv -- dwe_ythn157843.pdf dwe_157843.pdf
```

If you are happy with the `echo` result, remove it to actually perform the command.

Comment: Thank you! This  also worked.